# Creating custom angular filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

i have a json of items and a barcode scanner, the barcode scanner inputs directly into my app.

Now the items have a primary part number and a secondary part number, more often than not the result from the barcode scanner will be the primary part number, but i have to check with both to be sure.

I'm trying to implement a custom filter to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working, can anyone maybe let me know what i'm doing wrong ?

```
 storeApp.filter('barcodeScanner', function() {
                return function(parts, barcode) {
                   angular.forEach(parts, function (vals, key) {
                       if( !angular.isUndefined(vals.Part_Number) && vals.Part_Number !== null  )
                            if (angular.equals(vals.Part_Number,barcode)) 
                                return parts[key];
                   });
                   angular.forEach(parts, function(vals, key) {
                        if ( !angular.isUndefined(vals.Other_Part_Number) && vals.Other_Part_Number !== null )
                            if (angular.equals(vals.Other_Part_Number,barcode)) 
                                return parts[key];
                   });
                };
            });
```

i then call the filter later in the controller,

```
$scope.addItemToCart = function() {
                   $scope.shoppingCart.push($filter('barcodeScanner')($scope.parts, $scope.ItemToAdd));
                   console.log($scope.Cart.itemToAdd);
                   console.log($filter('barcodeScanner')($scope.parts, $scope.Cart.itemToAdd));
                   $scope.Cart.itemToAdd = "";
                   console.log($scope.shoppingCart);
                };
```

however the  result from the filter keeps returning undefined. i know for a fact that the entry i want does exist, because when i use a normal $filter('filter') it works fine, but i cannot risk such a widespread filter for my app.

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the forEach part of your function. A forEach function does not return a value. You are returning a value to your iterator function and since the forEach is not returning that returned value from the iterator then you will have nothing to push in your `$scope.shoppingCart.push($filter('barcodeScanner')($scope.parts, $scope.ItemToAdd));`

**Saving to a variable ie. `matchedPart` declared inside the anonymous factory(wrapper) function and returning it outside of the forEach function should solve the undefined:**

```
 storeApp.filter('barcodeScanner', function() {
            return function(parts, barcode) {

                // declare a variable here
                   var matchedPart;

               angular.forEach(parts, function (vals, key) {
                   if( !angular.isUndefined(vals.Part_Number) && vals.Part_Number !== null  )
                        if (angular.equals(vals.Part_Number,barcode)) 
                           // save it to new variable  
                           matchedPart = parts[key];
               });
               angular.forEach(parts, function(vals, key) {
                    if ( !angular.isUndefined(vals.Other_Part_Number) && vals.Other_Part_Number !== null )
                        if (angular.equals(vals.Other_Part_Number,barcode)) 
                            // save it to new variable  
                           matchedPart = parts[key];
               });
                  // return it outside the forEach function  
                  return matchedPart;
            };
        });
```

last note: 
I would also think you should refactor by combining your forEach functions. Not have 2 separate ones. Combining your isUndefined check with `!angular.isUndefined(vals.Part_Number) && !angular.isUndefined(vals.Other_Part_Number) && vals.Part_Number...`

Comment: Aaa was not aware about not being able to return from within a forEach, my reasoning behind separating them was that since it's much more common that the match will be with the primary part number, i could exit the function more quickly for most parts, but since the return doesn't work in the iterator, then combining them makes more sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.equals` you need to check `==` because `string` will not exactly equal to `number`

`angular.equals` is nothing but strongly check in javascript `===` which check both values are equal with their type or not.

`if(angular.equals(vals.Other_Part_Number,barcode))`

Changed to

`if(vals.Other_Part_Number == barcode)`

If you want to strictly check then you need to convert both the value to number using `parseInt` and then check

`if(angular.equals(parseInt(vals.Other_Part_Number),parseInt(barcode)))`

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the info, but the part numbers are actually stored as strings so this actually works fine :)